# Data frame with undesired variable in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new in Python, I created a data-frame from a for cycle, but when I inspect the data frame there are new variables (\n) and my original variable is unformatted (Numbers separated by blank spaces ). My code is:

```
for n in range(35,40):
 nuevo=print (n, file=open("loop3.txt", "a"))

ejemplo = open("loop3.txt")
print(ejemplo)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ejemplo)
df.columns = [['A','B','C']]

print(df)
```

Thanks in advance.
Rodrigo

Comment: Can you share a small snippet of the file loop3.txt? Without it it's difficult to replicate your problem and see what the issue might be. As a general rule if you can avoid text files and use something a bit more structured like a CSV (comma separated values) file you'll make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, below I attach a screen capture.

Comment: Below I create a new example that show the same problem without using save or import a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix the problem with the next code:

```
aa = []
for i in range(40):    
    aa.append(i)
print(aa)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(aa)
df2.columns = [['number']]

print(df2)

print (df2, file=open("df2.csv", "w"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I saving as csv, but I get the same results when I run print(df). I attach a view of file: loop3. csv, it did not show problem [capture screen csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfYqt.png)

Also I attach a screen capture of my print(df) [screen capture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxh03.png):

```
for n in range(35,40):
 nuevo=print (n, file=open("loop3.csv", "a"))

ejemplo = open("loop3.csv")
print(ejemplo)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(ejemplo)
df.columns = [['number1','number2??','I dont know']]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below , I show another example, avoiding importing or saving a file,  but is almost the same problem, when I print(df):

```
for n in range(40):
  print(n)
a = repr(n)
```

Here, I get 40 numbers in variable "a"

```
print(a)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(a)
df.columns = [['number']]
```

Here, almost 40 number that I got desappear and only get the last number (39) and unformatted (or split in 2 differents cases)

```
print(df)
```